# How to reuse of fragment with multi-tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabs

I have developed project using Fragments and Tabs at Bottom,
I use just one activity and all fragemnts and tab click is managed by tabHost and stack of fragment

I use this code [github link fragment_tab_study](https://github.com/iamjayanth/FragmentTabStudy) for setting tabs and maintaining stack of fragment

Now the issue is that we just push fragment(i.e replace fragment) so every time it call its onCreateView and all other method, I think this is a very big issue in this demo, as we click second time on tab1 it should only call its onResume method as happen in activity

is any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use replace of then in any case you have to start with onCreateView. If you dont want to recycle you can choose add method of transaction. But to replace is better in fragment terminology. You can even save transaction between fragment in back stack.

Please let me know if you have some other concern regarding fragment.

Thanks
Ankur

Comment: i just changed add inplace of replace in pushFragments method in AppMainTabActivity, but then it fails to open previous fragment when click on back button

Comment: @Jayesh using this way I don't think so that we can stop onCreateView of fragments. Yes if we use ViewPager with Fragments we can easily handle the scenario you want but let you know one point that in case of view pager once fragments loaded none of the cycle overridden method will call again.

So please let me know if you want a demo for viewpager with fragment.

Comment: I have already demo of viewpager with fragment, but not with tab, if you have demo of tabs give me link....